# React - Wait for complex method to finish before rendering

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to display a dashboard component, crunching a lot of data fetched from my redux store. This component takes a lot of time to render, mainly because of a single complex method.

Is it possible to render some kind of loader or placeholder while this method is processing ?

I tried doing so by using `ComponentDidMount`, but it seems like, because the method is part of my `render()` method, it will always be triggered first-hand.

Comment: is your method processing asynchronous action

Answer (score 0):

Yes! Check out [this](https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/loading-components-asynchronously-in-react-app-with-an-hoc-61ca27c4fda7) tutorial.

Loader:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

const asyncComponent = (importComponent) => {
    return class extends Component {
        state = {
            component: null
        }

        componentDidMount() {
            importComponent()
                .then(cmp => {
                    this.setState({component: cmp.default});
                });
        }

        render() {
            const C = this.state.component;
            return C ? <C {...this.props}/> : null;
        }
    }
};

export default asyncComponent;
```

Usage:

```
import React from 'react';
import asyncComponent from '../../hoc/asyncComponent';

const AsyncButton = asyncComponent(() => {
    return import('../Button');
});


const container = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Here goes an async loaded button component</h1>
            <AsyncButton/>
        </div>
    );
};

export default container;
```

or check out [this](https://github.com/f/react-wait) library.